# SQL Query based on common field

Tags: sql, sql-server

What SQL query do I need to use to get an alternative parts list based on a common reference number. The common reference in the Example below is ELS though the real table is over 100,000 rows with variable references.

Table A

```
**Reference     Part**
ELS           test1
ELS           test2  
ELS           test3
```

Result

```
**Part            Alternative Part**
test1           test2
test1           test3  
test2           test1
test2           test3
test3           test1  
test3           test2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `cross join`:

```
select t1.part, t2.part
from t t1 join
     t t2
     on t1.els = t2.els and t1.part <> t2.part;
```

Comment: Error running on entire table - Msg 1101, Level 17, State 10, Line 4
Could not allocate a new page for database 'TEMPDB' because of insufficient disk space in filegroup 'DEFAULT'. Create the necessary space by dropping objects in the filegroup, adding additional files to the filegroup, or setting autogrowth on for existing files in the filegroup.

Comment: @Emma . . . You probably have some  very large groups.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with a simple self join

```
create table #test (reference varchar(10), part varchar(10))
insert into #test values ('ELS', 'test1'), ('ELS', 'test2'), ('ELS', 'test3')

select t1.part as part, 
       t2.part as alternate_part
from   #test t1
  inner join #test t2 on t1.reference = t2.reference
where t1.part <> t2.part
order by 1

drop table #test
```

the result is this

```
part    alternate_part  
----    --------------  
test1   test2   
test1   test3   
test2   test1   
test2   test3   
test3   test1   
test3   test2
```